# How do I open a File Dialog box in IDEAScript?

Tags: ideascript

I would like to have the user select a file to import into my IDEA project as a part of an IDEAScript macro.  How can I create the File Dialog box and get the file the user selects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will open a File Dialog window and return the file path for the file the user chooses.

```
Function GetFileName()

    Dim ShellApp, Ret, s, i
    Set ShellApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

    Set Ret = ShellApp.BrowseForFolder(0, "Choose a file.", 16384)
    MsgBox Ret.ParentFolder.ParseName(Ret.Title).Path

End Function
```